# Not expected strange behaviour of ARC during deallocating instances

Tags: objective-c, automatic-ref-counting

I'm refreshing my knowledge in Objective-C world and now I'm testing some ARC with `__weak` local variables.

I have very simple code with such files `GAObject.h`

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
@interface GAObject : NSObject
+ (instancetype)create;
@end
```

Implementation of this interface `GAObject.h`

```
#import "GAObject.h"
@implementation GAObject
+ (instancetype)create {
    return [[GAObject alloc] init];
}
- (void)dealloc {
    NSLog(@"GAObject is being deallocated");
}
@end
```

So there is simple factory method `create` and I override `dealloc` method to watch if objects was deallocated when I expecting this. Now the funny part `main.m`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Learning/GAObject.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSLog(@"1");
        NSObject *o1 = [[GAObject alloc] init];
        NSObject * __weak weakObject = o1; // Line 1
        o1 = nil; // o1 should be deallocated because there is no strong references pointing to o1.
        NSLog(@"2");
        NSObject *o2 = [GAObject create]; // Line 2
        o2 = nil; // o2 should be deallocated here too but it is not deallocated. Why?
        NSLog(@"3");

        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

In the output I see this:

```
1
GAObject is being deallocated
2
3
```

But My expecting results should be:

```
1
GAObject is being deallocated
2
GAObject is being deallocated
3
```

If I create `o2` using factory method then I have this behaviour. If I create `o2` like this: `[[GAObject alloc] init]` then I get expected output. Also I noticed that when I remove line with `weakObject` I also get expected results. Can somebody explain it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because ARC still respects the Cocoa memory-management naming conventions.

Under those conventions, a method named `+create` returns a +0 reference. So, in the implementation of the method, ARC has to balance the +1 reference of the `alloc`/`init` pair by autoreleasing the reference.

Then, in `main()`, ARC has to assume it has received a +0 reference from the call to `+create`. If it needed the reference to survive the current scope, it would retain it, but it doesn't so it doesn't. The second `GAObject` instance would be deallocated when the autorelease pool is drained, but that will never happen because `UIApplicationMain()` never returns. If you use two separate autorelease pools, one for the code dealing with `GAObject`s and another for the call to `UIApplicationMain()`, I expect you'll get the result you expect.

If ARC did need the reference to survive, it would retain at the assignment to the strong variable and release when that variable is assigned a new value (including `nil`) or goes out of scope. ARC has a run-time optimization that an autorelease-return in a callee and a retain of the returned value in the caller cancel each other out, such that the object is never put in the autorelease pool. If this were happening, you would get your expected results.

In fact, my expectation is that the compiler initially would emit that retain and release even in your case, but a subsequent pass removes redundant retains and releases. Your example has the release immediately follow the retain, which makes it even more obvious to the compiler that the pair are redundant. Because the retain gets removed, that autorelease optimization doesn't kick in, and a reference to your object really does get put into the autorelease pool.

If your method were named `+newGAObject`, then the naming conventions would mean it returns a +1 reference and this all changes. (Of course, as it stands, your `+create` method is just doing the same thing as the built-in `+new` method, except for the autorelease that ARC has to add. So, you could just change the calling code to use `+new` and that would also sidestep this issue.)

I don't know why the line with `weakObject` matters. But, since the behavior you're seeing depends on certain optimizations, anything that could tweak the optimizations can change the outcome.

Comment: Thanks For Your reply. Indead changing name of the factory method to newObject helped in this situation. I wonder why in all courses about Objective-C nobody will tell You that. I read a lot of documents about best practices in designing factory methods but I didn't find info about this `new` prefix and how it is important in memory management under ARC. So if method is named with `new` prefix then compiler will assume that my factory method is return +1 reference. I wonder why this is not covered in Google Objective-C Style guide?

Comment: Well, a factory method that doesn't start with "new" is perfectly fine, safe, and normal (e.g. `+[NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingFromURL:error:]`). What ARC was doing was correct. There was no real problem, only a difference from your expectations. The naming conventions are described [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html).

Comment: @MarcinKapusta http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch12.html#_what_arc_is_and_what_it_does "When your code receives an object as the returned value of a method call, ARC looks at the opening word (or words) of the camelCased method name... If the opening word of the name of that method is `alloc`, `init`, `new`, `copy`, or `mutableCopy`, ARC assumes that the object it returns comes with an incremented retain count that will need to be balanced with a corresponding release."

Comment: hmm. I'm expecting that a factory method will return an object that after assigning it to one variable (strong reference by default) will have retain count == 1. I discovered that You can add attribute that will help ARC to treat this method as with `new` prefix: `+ (instancetype)create __attribute__((objc_method_family(new)));`. This can be putted in `@interface` or `@implementation`

Comment: @MarcinKapusta - You _can_ do that, but it’s a really bad idea. Objective-C and ARC have well defined naming conventions that dictate how memory management is performed, notably for the purposes of interacting with manual memory management code that failed to conform to Apple’s four memory management rules. The above is not a good use case for this.

Comment: @matt - Above, you talk about method names that start with “`alloc`, `init`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`” ... The `init` doesn’t belong in that list. It’s just method names that start with `alloc`, `new`, `copy` or `mutableCopy`.

Comment: Thanks Rob for the info. I just understand it :) The created object with the help of factory methods like `create` or `stringWith...` are set for autoreleasing. I put my code in application loop and it seems that they are get deallocated at the end of run loop. I suppose run loop has it's own `@autoreleasepool` or something similar that `release` any such objects created this way. Thanks everybody for let me understand this.

Comment: Yep, there is an runloop that is drained when you yield back to the run loop.

Comment: @Rob `-init` is kinda weird.   It sort of does a "retain preservation dance".  That is, if the method returns a *different* instance than the one that was called, the different instance does need a +1 retain count.   So, it sort of does belong on the list *but* with the additional caveat that `self` in the context of that method is +1 on entry.

Comment: I've seen `-init` referred to as a -1/+1 method. I forget where. Maybe even Apple's docs. The -1 balances the +1 of `+alloc`, the +1 is for the object it returns. If they're the same object, it's a wash, but since it can be (and often is) a different object, the distinction matters. There's a reason I elided all of this by discussing the `alloc`/`init` pair in my answer. ;)

Comment: @KenThomases That is what we called it on the runtime team and we worked closely with the documentation team (if you are designing API, involve the docs folks as early as possible;  if you can't explain it to them and they can't explain it back?  Sure sign that your API is poorly designed).